# Is it possible to use a constant for the identifier of a storyboard segue in Xcode's Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, segue

I was wondering if it is at all possible to use constants defined in, say, a Swift source file named Constants.swift in the "Identifier" field for a Storyboard Segue in Xcode's Interface Builder. For example, if I have a constant declared like this:

let SHOW_PHOTOS_SCENE_SEGUE_ID = "showPhotos"

can I use something like $SHOW_PHOTOS_SCENE_SEGUE_ID in the "Identifier" field of the Attributes Inspector for the Storyboard Segue? I would like to do this to prevent errors due to misspelling the ID in either source code or in the storyboard.

Comment: I would like to do this as well. Did you come up with something yet?

Comment: @lostintranslation No, I haven't.

Comment: It's so amateur to not have constants. You could try making an extension that overrides UIViewController and ads a custom list of IDs that you have designed from statics.